# ldrtl-xlarge layout doesn't get really xlarge

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an Android app for a **tablet**, and the app will be in Hebrew language which **Right to Left**, when i create a layout for **ldrtl** it creates it well, and when I create a **xlarge** layout it also creates it will ( I can see it in the design mode big), but when I try to create a **ldrtl-xlarge** layout, it **just makes it ldrtl, but not really xlarge**( it still the regular size view)!
anyone have any ideas?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.raghdak.wardm.smartcourierclient.newShipmentActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
    android:layout_width="114dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="@string/btnBack"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/urgentCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="97dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="@string/urgent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dueDateText"
    android:layout_width="94dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/dueDate"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/urgentCheckBox" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/claimantText"
    android:layout_width="92dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/claimant"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dueDateText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/claimantEditText"
    android:layout_width="217dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.887"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.021" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dueDateEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="date"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.888"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/addressText"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/address"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/claimantText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addressEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.888"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/claimantEditText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.033" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_width="84dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/receiverName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addressText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.888"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addressEditText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.019" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phoneText"
    android:layout_width="83dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/phone"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phoneEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.888"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameEditText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/poboxText"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/pobox"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phoneText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/poboxEditText"
    android:layout_width="215dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.888"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phoneEditText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.071" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:text="@string/save"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

images:
[ldrtl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h6ES.png)

[xlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCkPl.png)

[ldrtl-xlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KtWH.png)

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: added the specific layout code, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

After searching I found that this is an Android Studio issue, the best solution is to create the layout regular as ldtrl, and then simply in the android studio Design mode catch the right bottom edge of the screen and then too many resize options will appear choose which one you want buy dragging the screen to the relevant place, this thing will create a custom ldrtl layout (in my case custom ldrtl-xlarge layout), and you can still work with it as a really big screen with right to left language direction.